# How do I slice a string if whitespace is detected?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have some strings coming in one-by-one. If they are more than 15 characters long, I'd like to slice all the content after 15 characters, but not before a white-space is detected(to keep it readable).

My logic currently is something along these lines:

```
                const text  = "Microsoft Server 2012 R2"; // text.length = 24
                let newStr = '';
                if(text.length > 15 ){ // true
                    newStr = text.slice(0, 15)
                }
                console.log(newStr);
                // Desired output: "Microsoft Server
                // Current output: "Microsoft Serve"
```

Comment: `split` returns an array which I think is not what you want

Comment: so if 15th character is inside word, you want to keep the whole word or delete whole word?

Comment: @MasterYushi you are right, it is slice. I was testing some stuff, sorry.

Comment: @Luke keep it :)

Comment: Do you want to truncate, or split the string in two (or more)?

Comment: @ClasG Slice the string. I don't need to keep the remainder of the content after the whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex replace to get your job done. This matches 0 or more non-white-space characters after first 15 characters in input.

```js
var s = 'Microsoft Server 2012 R2'
var r = s.replace(/^(.{15}\S*).*$/, '$1')

console.log(r)
//=> Microsoft Server
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJF1Vc/1)

Comment: Is the `replace` more efficient that doing the same logic with a `RegExp` and then get the first group ? Or is it just for shortness

Comment: It is just for shortness @AxelH. We could do `exec` or `match` and get the matched string as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may match *any* first 15 chars with `[^]{15}` / `[\s\S]{15}` and then match 0 or more non-whitespace chars with `\S*`:

```js
const text  = "Microsoft Server 2012 R2";
let newStr = (m=text.match(/^[^]{15}\S*/)) ? m[0] : "";
console.log(newStr);
```

Note that `.` matches any characters *other* than line break chars, that is why I suggest `[^]` (non-nothing) or its portable equivalent `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could match the first wanted letters and take the charcters until a space is found.

```js
var string = "Microsoft Server 2012 R2",
    short = string.match(/^.{15}[^ ]*/)[0];
    
console.log(short);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function hasWhiteSpace(SubText) {
  return /\s/g.test(SubText);
}
```

Call this function and check for white space in substring i.e. SubText which is substring of text till 15 charactors. thus you will get a boolen value if that substring contains a whitespace. This function will also test for TABs Present.